# Spring Boot project in IntelliJ community edition

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle, intellij-idea

I am new to IntelliJ Community edition. Can anyone help me with creating spring boot project in intelliJ Community edition. For ultimate edition there is spring-boot initializer but I cannot find anything  for community edition. I followed this links but cannot find any solutions

- "[*Create Spring Boot Project with IntelliJ Community (FREE) Edition in 5 mins*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=397QPCAjm0o)"
- "[*Getting Started with SpringBoot in Intellij IDEA Community Edition*](https://sivalabs.in/2016/09/getting-started-springboot-intellij-idea-community-edition/)"

Comment: why can't you use spring-tool-suit(sts)?

Comment: There is no bundled support for Spring boot in Community edition: https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/editions_comparison_matrix.html

Comment: I don't understand why IntelliJ is not giving us this feature for free in the Community Edition and **force** us to go to `https://start.spring.io/.` What's the rationale? If it's their profiler, fine, it makes 100% sense. Come on IntelliJ, you can do better ;-)

Answer (score 33):

You can install a plugin called `Spring Assistant`:
[image: Spring Assistant]
Now you can use the initializer as:
[image: Using initializer]
Personally, however, I use Spring initializer at start.spring.io

**EDIT: Adding run configuration**

Select **Edit Configuration** from the **Run** menu
[image: Run menu]
Now in the dialog box, lick on the `+` button and select `Application`.
[image: Run Configuration dialog]
Now you just need to provide the name of the main class. You could click on the browse button(`...`) to get a list of files having `main(...)`.
[image: Select class with main()]

Comment: See my answer above if anybody is not able to find `Sprint Assistant` while searching in Plugins in IntelliJ IDEA Community.

Comment: Not compatible with the version of your running IDE (IntelliJ IDEA 2022.2.1)

Comment: This plugin was last updated 4 years back. You can try using: https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/18622-spring-boot-helper/

Comment: Spring Boot Helper is a paid module... @Prashant :/

Answer (score 8):

Pretty simple, as both link you attached say you created your project with [Spring Initializr](https://start.spring.io/), and if it is a maven project, then follow these steps mentioned below:

- click on **File** option
- click **Open** option
- navigate to your project and choose **pom.xml** file [if not a maven project, choose your configuration.xml file, if something else, just select the project folder]
- press **Ok**. And you are done
- now, open idea terminal and run **mvn clean install**(I assume you have installed maven) or, just **select project->right click->choose maven-> click on Reimport maven option**. Now run **mvn clean build** All are set now.

Answer (score 7):

If you have done your spring project with  [SPRING IO](https://start.spring.io)

Then You can import it as maven project and follow this steps to import spring project

1. Open IntelliJ IDEA
2. You can see  Welcome screen, click Import Project.
   The Select File
3. Navigate to your Maven project and select
4. Click OK.

Answer (score 6):

You can follow these steps.

1. Click on Add / Edit configuration
   [image]
2. Then select configuration type as application.
   [image]
3. Fill in appropriate details.
   **Note**: In place of `<no module>` add directory / module in which the entry class is present.
   [image]
4. Save the configuration and click on Run / Debug symbol shown in first screenshot.

Answer (score 3):

As everyone else mentioned, use https://start.spring.io to start your Spring Boot project. Download and open in IntelliJ Community Edition.

Where you will face some difficulty is in running the project; - Ultimate Edition has a Spring Boot plugin that is missing in Community Edition.

You may get errors especially if your main folder of your project is one level higher than the root of your IntelliJ project.

For this, use the Maven run option.

`Edit Configuration` and Click the `+` to create a new Maven configuration

[image: maven run]

Answer (score 1):

Extending [@Prashant's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58055827/4567504)

If you are not able to find `Spring Assistant` plugin within IntelliJ Community Edition, Go to [Plugin's website](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/10229-spring-assistant) and then click on `GET` button, Choose Compatibility with `IntelliJ IDEA Community` and then click `Download`.

[image: Spring Assistant Plugin Website]

The rest of the procedure remains the same as described by @Prashant.

Also if you want to change your Port, then select `Modify Options` and select `Add VM Options`, and paste

> -Dserver.port=8090

in that VM Options textbox and then run the application.

[image: Modifying Configuration for port]

Comment: "Plugin 'Spring Assistant' (version 0.12.0) was explicitly marked as incompatible with the current version of the IDE"

Comment: Any replacement since its incompatible with 2021?

Answer (score 1):

Just go to the below mentioned:

https://start.spring.io/

Fill the information regarding Project(Maven, Java, spring-version(Select version only
have digits(for eg:2.6.2))). Don't select "snapshot" version.

Fill project Metadata information and click on Generate file. It will create jar file. Unzip it and open your IntelliJ and select "Open->select this Unzip folder and select "pom.xml" file inside this package and open as project.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the spring initialiser, in my experience no where else do you need an ultimate edition to work with spring boot, you can use [Spring Intialiser](https://start.spring.io/)

But there is a plugin as rightly mentioned by other [Spring assistant](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/10229-spring-assistant) which you can download from the plugin section which you can access from setting inside intellJ Idea.

**For configuration instead of actually going in the edit configuration option of intellJ Idea you can just run the application and that would automatically have your configuration loaded and there onwards you can always use it.**