# application.properties is greyed out in IntelliJ

Tags: java, spring-boot, api

I am trying to develop spring boot server but I am encountering two problems

1. everything in application.properties is greyed out

[image]

2. Changing the database name is not affecting any API response. For example, I have an API which get user from the database **"testewe"**, so if I change the database name to anything else and then hit the API, it will return the same user which are present in testwe database, although in reality the later database does not even exist.

Dependency added

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.6</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.concious</groupId>
    <artifactId>dummapp</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>dummapp</name>
    <description>NA</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>

        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!--s3 dependencies-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
            <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-s3</artifactId>
            <version>1.12.454</version>
        </dependency>
        <!--s3 dependencies-->

        <!--scalar dependency-->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.imgscalr</groupId>
            <artifactId>imgscalr-lib</artifactId>
            <version>4.2</version>
            <type>jar</type>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!--scalar dependency-->
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

I have tried almost every solution from the internet, but none of them seems to work. Please help me resolve the issue.

Comment: 1. Is it "community Edition" and the warning says x time "Unused property"!? 2. `datasource.name` is not "database specific" but spring/sql client specific (you can choose it freely" https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/application-properties.html#application-properties.data.spring.datasource.name :)

Comment: and for 1. : If so, then you have to live with/can ignore the gray/warnings ... https://www.jetbrains.com/products/compare/?product=idea&product=idea-ce , https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360003254100-IntelliJ-Community-Edition-and-Spring-Boot- , https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/6018317773074-Intellij-idea-community-edition-with-Spring-boot- , https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58055770/spring-boot-project-in-intellij-community-edition

Comment: @xerx593 yes its community edition

Comment: @xerx593 problem is not to live with warning , if i have to change database name ,then its still using previous database name only.Although in log its will be using new database name

Comment: Db name in this screenshot is (after localhost:3306/...) test ! (in url/other properties...see 1. link)